# I've been trying to install react-native-maps to y project but whenever i rebuild my app it gives me this error continuously

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps

I am using Gradle 8.0 and it won't allow me to build the app with the react-native-maps installed. I have tried every solution like clearing the cache and even compiling it on another device where it is compiled properly but I keep getting this error.

```
Task :react-native-maps:generateDebugRFile FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
37 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 34 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-maps:generateDebugRFile'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-maps:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-symbol-with-package-name, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
      > Could not find react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.71.0-rc.0/react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 54s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-maps:generateDebugRFile'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-maps:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-symbol-with-package-name, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
      > Could not find react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.71.0-rc.0/react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 54s
```

Here is the info of my device on which im trying to make this project

```
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.19044
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
    Memory: 1.05 GB / 7.89 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.17.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: Not Found
    npm: 8.15.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    Watchman: Not Found
  SDKs:
    Android SDK: Not Found
    Windows SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Not Found
    Visual Studio: 17.3.32819.101 (Visual Studio Community 2022)
  Languages:
    Java: 18.0.2.1
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.1.0 => 18.1.0
    react-native: 0.70.4 => 0.70.4
    react-native-windows: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Help would be greatly appreciated

an error solution help that  can build the project

Comment: Did you try the suggested steps? By that I mean - `Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.` and all the other suggestions in the error report.

Comment: yes didn't work